# Scoping issue between thread and process?

Tags: python, multithreading, process, scope

So why does "YES" never get printed in the following example? I need to access `self.stuff` of class `one()` from class `two()`, how ever `self.one.stuff` in class `two()` always prints an empty dictionary even after I add to it in class `one()`.

```
import threading
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

class one():
    def __init__(self):
        self.stuff = {}
        self.two = two(self)
    def start(self):
        while True:
            print "Process Loop"
            time.sleep(2)
            self.stuff['hi'] = 1
            print self.stuff

class two():
    def __init__(self, o):
        self.one = o

        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.doit, args=())
        self.thread.setDaemon(True)
        self.thread.start()


    def doit(self):
        print "Thread Loop"
        while True:
            if 'hi' in self.one.stuff:
                print "YES"
            time.sleep(3)


ooo = one()
p = Process(target=ooo.start)
p.start()
```

This results in

```
Thread Loop
Process Loop
{'hi': 1}
Process Loop
{'hi': 1}
Process Loop
{'hi': 1}
Process Loop
{'hi': 1}
Process Loop
```

If I don't start one() as a process the output is as I expect it to be though:

```
ooo = one()
ooo.start()

Process Loop
Thread Loop
{'hi': 1}
Process Loop
YES
{'hi': 1}
Process Loop
YES
{'hi': 1}
Process Loop
```

Comment: processes do not share state.

Comment: In other words, each process gets a *copy* of `ooo` (that is bound to the method).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - in this case, though, we're dealing with two threads running in the same process. They both have the same instance of `one`.

Comment: @NathanVērzemnieks I admit that I'm still trying to wrap my head around it...

Comment: Yeah I'm a bit bemused too.

Comment: Well! It turns out they're not actually the same process; if you print `os.getpid()` from `one.start` and `two.doit` they're different. `one.start` is running in a subprocess, but `two` is running in the main process!?

Comment: Oh, of course - because the `two` instance is in fact created and started in the main process. Sorry for the comment spam ^_^

Comment: Well, this question is actually great example of very basic differences between processes and threads and shared state. Classy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the `one` instance, it's created in the main process. That means the `two` instance has already been created, and its `doit` thread has already been started, in the main process.

When you run `ooo.start` in a subprocess, it no longer has access to the original `two` instance and vice-versa - the new process has a copy of each instance, but the `two` instance in the subprocess isn't doing anything, and the `one` instance in the main process isn't either.

In short: @juanpa.arrivallaga's comment is the answer - processes do not share state.